# ngx drag drop - unbind mouse event

Tags: javascript, angular, drag-and-drop, ngx-drag-drop

I am using ngx Drag Drop https://github.com/reppners/ngx-drag-drop and it is working quite well.
However i need to achieve one functionality that i have described in their issues but no response yet...

https://github.com/reppners/ngx-drag-drop/issues/78

I have done it with jquery easyUi in pure jquery but in not able to achieve in angular. Can anybody please assist?

jquery EasyUI Code

```
$( ".ui-widget-content" ).draggable({
  cursor: "move",
  scroll: true,
  appendTo:'body',
  onStartDrag: function(e) {
    $(document).unbind('mouseup'); --> this is the trick that keeps dragged element with cursor
  }
});
```

I have created JSBin for easyUI as well - https://jsbin.com/tohexowubu/edit?html,output

I want to achieve same effect in ngxDragDrop

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want the user to have to click again when they are ready to place the object, rather than just release the mouse button?

Comment: yeah.. click to drop.. once person will drag then it sticks to mouse and then click to drop